# MCP2221A and ESP32-S3 Auto Program circuit?

Tags: uart, converter, esp32, reset, enable

I am currently trying to make my own development board but have run into a bit of a pickle.
I want to be able to Auto Program the ESP32 since pressing a button each time is not something that I would like to do. I do know how to make an Auto Program circuit but I am not sure how I would wire it up to this converter since it is my first time using it! :-D

TLDR: Is there a way to make an Auto Program circuit with the MCP2221A and ESP32-S3 and still keep the GP0 and GP1 pins to indicate RX & TX traffic? (The input voltage is 5V and I will be using an isolator for stepping down to 3.3V for the ESP32 module. If this is relevant)

[image]

This is the current schematic of the MCP2221A that I have drawn.

[image]

And this is the ESP32 module.

Comment: Maybe you can explain what an *Auto Program circuit* is or does?

Comment: If *Auto Program circuit* refers to the circuit for resetting the ESP and putting it into bootloader mode via a serial connection, then the MCP2221A won't work. That circuit uses the DTR and RTS signals, which are not available on the MCP2221A. You could emulate them using GPIOs; but then you will likely need to create a replacement for *esptool*.

Comment: Why are you add a USB-to-serial chip anyway? Is the built-in USB-to-UART bridge not sufficient?

Comment: @Codo Oh, ok. Thought it could do that. Guess I will take a look at the CH340C chip then. Or maybe the MCP2200 since it has RTS and CTS pinouts?

Comment: @Codo I am not sure that the ESP32 has built in USB-to-UART? Cannot see it anywhere in the datasheets?

Comment: See https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s3_datasheet_en.pdf, ch "3.5.12 USB Serial/JTAG Controller". It does not apply to the original ESP32.